# Копирование данных между книгами. Ускорение времени работы кода вба

Tags: excel, vba

Есть файл `книга2`, в него попадают данные с `книга3` по прописанному макросу

К сожалению, возможно, из-за больших объемов и надстроек макросов в файле, работа макроса может занять 10-20 минут. Различные решения оптимизации пробовал добавить, но пока безуспешно.

Количество и объем данных примерно занимает где-то 6 колонок на 200 и более строк, но почему-то процесс идет слишком долго. Полагаю, одна из возможных проблем - это то, что я пытаюсь добавить этот макрос в процесс при изменении в диапозоне `A:A` в `книга2`.

```
Function ifopen(w As String) As Boolean
    On Error Resume Next
    ifopen = Workbooks(w).Name <> ""
End Function

Public Sub hyfre1()
    Application.ErrorCheckingOptions.BackgroundChecking = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.StatusBar = False

If ifopen("книга3") = False Then
Workbooks.Open "C:\Users\nshuvalov\Desktop\книга3.xlsm", ReadOnly:=True
End If

   Dim LastRow As Long
   Dim LastRow2 As Long

    LastRow = Workbooks("книга2").Sheets("план").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    LastRow2 = Workbooks("книга3").Sheets("выручка").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

          With Workbooks("книга2").Sheets("план")


            For s = 2 To LastRow
                For xx = 2 To LastRow2
                If Workbooks("книга2").Sheets("план").Cells(s, 1) = Workbooks("книга3").Sheets("выручка").Cells(xx, 1) Then

                   Workbooks("книга3").Sheets("выручка").Cells(xx, 6).Copy
                   Workbooks("книга2").Sheets("план").Cells(s, 2).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                   Workbooks("книга3").Sheets("выручка").Cells(xx, 3).Copy
                   Workbooks("книга2").Sheets("план").Cells(s, 3).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                   Workbooks("книга3").Sheets("выручка").Cells(xx, 2).Copy
                   Workbooks("книга2").Sheets("план").Cells(s, 4).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                   Workbooks("книга3").Sheets("выручка").Cells(xx, 5).Copy
                   Workbooks("книга2").Sheets("план").Cells(s, 5).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
               End If
                Next
           Next
        End With

    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.StatusBar = True

Application.ErrorCheckingOptions.BackgroundChecking = True
End Sub
```

[image: 1]
[image: 2]

Comment: Работать с ячейками - гарантированные тормоза. Загрузите сразу все данные в двумерный массив, и там обрабатывайте, гоня результат в другой массив, а затем сразу весь его выплёвывайте на лист.

Comment: Буфер обмена не используй. Взял значение, записал значение.

Comment: попробуйте рабоать с данными в книгах как с массивами, учитывая что у вас обычное копирование, проблем не должно быть.

Comment: @Akina, что-то сомнительно, что можно получить все значения в массиве не перебирая ячейки.

Comment: Спасибо за идеи, был бы признателен если бы был бы пример похожий как с таким работать.

Comment: @Qwertiy `Dim tmp() : tmp = Range("A1:C3").Value` - проделай в дебаге...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Dim Src As Sheet, Dest as Sheet
Set Src = Workbooks("книга3").Sheets("выручка")
Set Dest = Workbooks("книга2").Sheets("план")
```

> ```
> Workbooks("книга3").Sheets("выручка").Cells(xx, 6).Copy
> Workbooks("книга2").Sheets("план").Cells(s, 2).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
> ```

```
Dest.Cells(s, 2).Value = Src.Cells(xx, 6).Value
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное, правда намного шустрее работает

Answer (score 2):

На массивах гораздо быстрее. К объектам листа обращаемся только для получения данных и выгрузки результата.

```
Sub OpenBook_()
    If ifopen("книга3") = False Then
        With Application: .ScreenUpdating = False: .DisplayAlerts = False: End With
        Workbooks.Open "C:\Users\nshuvalov\Desktop\книга3.xlsm", ReadOnly:=True
        With Application: .ScreenUpdating = True: .DisplayAlerts = True: End With
    End If
End Sub

Function ifopen(w As String) As Boolean
    On Error Resume Next
    ifopen = Workbooks(w).Name <> ""
End Function

' --------------------------------------- '

Public Sub hyfre1()
    Dim aProfit(), aPlan()
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim i As Long, n As Long

    Call OpenBook_

    With Workbooks("книга3").Sheets("выручка")
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row
        If LastRow < 2 Then Exit Sub
        aProfit = .Range("A1:F" & LastRow).Value
    End With

    With Workbooks("книга2").Sheets("план")
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row
        If LastRow < 2 Then Exit Sub
        aPlan = .Range("A1:E" & LastRow).Value

        For i = 2 To UBound(aPlan)
            For n = 2 To UBound(aProfit)
                If aPlan(i, 1) = aProfit(n, 1) Then
                    aPlan(i, 2) = aProfit(n, 6)
                    aPlan(i, 3) = aProfit(n, 3)
                    aPlan(i, 4) = aProfit(n, 2)
                    aPlan(i, 5) = aProfit(n, 5)
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next n
        Next i

        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        .Range("A1:E5" & LastRow).Value = aPlan
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End With
End Sub
```

Если номера заказов в двух книгах по возрастанию, то можно еще ускорить - вложенный цикл просматривать не со второй, а с последней найденной строки. Объявить еще одну переменную и изменить фрагмент кода:

```
k = 2

For i = 2 To UBound(aPlan)
    For n = k To UBound(aProfit)
        If aPlan(i, 1) = aProfit(n, 1) Then
            k = n + 1
            aPlan(i, 2) = aProfit(n, 6)
```

Comment: `aPlan = .Range("A1:E" & LastRow).Value` точно не `Value2` должно быть?

Comment: Нет, одна переменная использована дважды (небольшая, но экономия памяти)

Comment: О, вопрос не о 'LastRow/LastRow2'... Да, обычно берем '.Value'